# SQL subquery and using letter X after parantheses

Tags: sql, subquery

Here is my query

```
SELECT deptno,
    sum(distinct sal) as total_sal,
    sum(bonus) as total_bonus
FROM (
    SELECT  e.empno,
            e.ename,
            e.sal,
            e.deptno,
            e.sal*case when eb.type is null then 0
                       when eb.type = 1 then .1
                       when eb.type = 2 then .2
                       else .3 end as bonus
    FROM EMP e left outer join EMP_BONUS eb
      on (e.empno = eb.empno)
    WHERE e.deptno = 10 
    ) X <----------- if I don't use this I get an error
GROUP BY deptno
```

If I omit the X, I get an error saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. Can anybody explain the purpose of that 'X'?

Comment: It is called a table alias.  Some databases require it for subqueries in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 3):

It is called a table aliases, which is required by some databases for subqueries in the `from` clause.

More importantly, your query is probably not doing what you think it is doing.  It miscalculates the total salary when two employees in the department have the same salary.

The query is trickier than it seems.  Try this instead:

```
select e.deptno, sum(e.sal), sum(e.sal * eb.bonus)
from emp e left outer join 
     (select eb.empno,
             sum(case when eb.type is null then 0.0
                      when eb.type = 1 then 0.1
                      when eb.type = 2 then 0.2
                      else 0.3
                 end) as bonus
      from emp_bonus eb
      group by eb.empno
     ) db
     on e.empno = eb.empno
where e.deptno = 10
```

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same thing. In this example though, author used distinct salaries so we wouldn't run into the problem that you have mentioned but thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

X is the 'name' of the table inside the brackets which is the result of the inner select query

That is, when your data comes from a subquery rather than a named table, you *have* to give it a name/alias.

(I'm assuming this is t-sql from the look of that Case statement)

Comment: Off the top of your head, do you know why certain databases require the alias while others do not (e.g. Oracle)?  I don't know, but am curious.

Comment: Adherence to sql standards across different platforms is very vague and so this is just one of hundreds of differences. And maybe the sql standards dont even address this particular case. At the end of the day, people dont often need to run the same sql on different platforms so it doesn't matter that much. As opposed to say, how important it is that browsers adhere to JS and CSS standards.